# Arrays contain the same elements but in a different order in Jest

Tags: jestjs

I need to make sure that everything in arrayA is in arrayB the same number of times(The order is not important).

How should I do that or is there an API for that?

```js
expect([2,1,2]).???([2,2,1]) // expect:pass

expect([3,2,1]).???([1,2,3]) // expect:pass

expect([2,2,2,1]).???([2,2,1]) // expect:error
```

Comment: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comments.

Use `jest-extended` to add additional matchers to Jest's default.

[toIncludeSameMembers](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers) API

```js
test('passes when arrays match in a different order', () => {
  expect([1, 2, 3]).toIncludeSameMembers([3, 1, 2]);
  expect([{ foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'qux' }]).toIncludeSameMembers([{ baz: 'qux' }, { foo: 'bar' }]);
});
```